# Creating Relationships in Neo4J using Spring-Data

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I want to create a relationship in neo4j where a Person has a list of friends. I can do this in two ways using spring-data.

a) Create a class Person with a List repesenting friends and annotate the same with @Relationship.

```
@NodeEntity(label="Person")
public class Person {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    @Relationship(type = "FRIEND_WITH")
    List<Person> friends; 
}
```

b) Create the Person object without any List and create the relationship of "FRIEND_WITH" with Cypher like

```
@Query "CREATE (a)-[FRIEND_WITH]->(b)"
```

What are the advantages/disadvanages of both the approaches ?

Answer (score 2):

Wherever possible you should manage entities and relationships in your domain model using code, not queries. The advantage of doing it in code is that your domain objects and the graph will remain in sync. The underlying Object Graph Mapper using by SDN does not understand what your queries are doing and so cannot make any changes to your domain model for you. This means that every time you mutate the database using a query, you will potentially need to reload all your objects again.

Comment: Neo4J supports both unidirectional and bidirectional relationships. So one must be armed with custom queries, if one wishes to play with the directions, while keeping the java class data-structure fixed. I was feeling like, it would be better to separate out the relationships from the class structure and dynamically create or delete the same through cypher as and when required. I just want to know your decision on the same.

Comment: Strictly speaking Neo4j supports bidirectional traversals: a relationship is always defined with a direction, but you may traverse it from either end. 

I'm not sure what you mean by 'play with directions', but SDN 4 supports INCOMING, OUTGOING and UNDIRECTED edge directions. UNDIRECTED is useful when you have a semantically reflexive relationship between two nodes - e.g. (Person)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(Person). Here you don't care about the direction, you just want to make sure that two friends are mutually connected in your domain. 

What is the use case you feel compelled to use queries for?

Comment: Suppose I have a Person A who is following a number of other Persons like in social networks. So there is a "List<Person>" in the Person object A which contains the list of Persons he/she is following. This is an outgoing relation. To get the persons whom A is following, i just need to traverse the list. Now, some other persons may also be following A. So, to get all those Persons  who are following A, I need to write a custom query because the previous list will only give me the persons whom A is following

Answer (score 2):

I am adding a second answer because I can't format code in comments, but something like this will work out of the box, and doesn't require any queries.

```
public class Person {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type="FOLLOWS", direction = "OUTGOING")
    private Set<Person> followees = new HashSet<>();

    @Relationship(type="FOLLOWS", direction = "INCOMING")
    private Set<Person> followers = new HashSet<>();

    public void follow(Person p) {
        this.followees.add(p);
        p.followers.add(this);
    }

    public void unfollow(Person p) {
        this.followees.remove(p);
        p.followers.remove(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Vince, I appreciate your help. Its not that I am deliberately disagreeing with you but I am truely trying to  learn about handling Neo4J. Coming to the point, in the above case, whenever there is a "follow" relationship, I have to update two objects, the Person object representing the "Follower" and the one representing the "Followee" as for both of them either the follower list or the followee list will change.  Similarly, it will also happen in case of unfollow. Whereas, if we create a relationship through cypher, no updation of objects is required and no maintaining of the two lists.

Comment: Souma, you asked a question about the advantages and disadvantages of using Cypher queries to mutate the graph in the context of SDN 4/ OGM, and I replied, giving an accurate answer, together with the reasons for it. You then asked another specific question in the subsequent comments, to which I gave a second reply, which is also accurate. I don't know what else I can do to help here, perhaps reading the SDN documentation will help you decide whether using an OGM is really what you want to do. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/